# Using linq how do i remove multiple records from a cross reference table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My Database contains 4 tables:

```
TABLE TBLCARTITEM (CART_ID, ITEM_ID, PROMOTION_ID, many more cart item fields) 
TABLE XREFCARTITEMPROMOTION (CART_ID, ITEM_ID, PROMOTION_ID) 
TABLE TBLPROMOTION (PROMOTION_ID, PROMOTION_TYPE_ID, many more promotion fields)
TABLE TBLITEM (ITEM_ID, many more item fields)
```

The XREFCARTIEMPROMOTION table is a cross reference table that creates a many-to-many relationship between TBLCARTITEM and TBLPROMOTION.  TBLITEM is related to both TBLCARTITEM and XREFCARTITEMPROMOTION.

I am trying to use linq to remove multiple records from the XREFCARTIEMPROMOTION table specified above.  Right now i can only remove a single record.

My script looks like so:

```
        using (WSE webStoreContext = new WSE()){

        XREFCARTITEM dbItem = WebStoreDelegates.selectCartItems.Invoke(webStoreContext).ByItemID(itemId).ByCartID(cartId).ToList().SingleOrDefault();


    if (dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTION != null)
    dbItem.TBLPROMOTION.Remove(WebStoreDelegates.selectPromotions.Invoke(webStoreContext).ByID(dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTION.PROMOTION_ID).ToList().SingleOrDefault()); 
}
```

the selectCartItems Delegate:

```
public static Func<WSE, IQueryable<XREFCARTITEM>> selectCartItems =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<WSE, IQueryable<XREFCARTITEM>>(
            (cart) => from c in cart.XREFCARTITEM.Include("TBLITEM").Include("TBLPROMOTION")
                      select c);
```

the selectPromotions Delegate:

```
public static Func<WSE, IQueryable<TBLPROMOTION>> selectPromotions =
CompiledQuery.Compile<WSE, IQueryable<TBLPROMOTION>>(
    (cart) => from c in cart.TBLPROMOTION
              select c);
```

Filters byItemID and byCartID will bring back all instances of this item in this cart.
Filter byID just brings back a single promotion.

My removal process is only removing a single record out of the XREFCARTITEMPROMOTION table.  I would like to remove all the filtered records from my dbitem's XREFCARTITEMPROMOTION table at this point.

I have tried setting the entity key to null, but this doesn't seem to make a difference. `dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTIONReference.EntityKey = null;`

My question is how do i remove multiple records from a cross reference table given the code above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answered my own question:

replace - if (dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTION != null)    dbItem.TBLPROMOTION.Remove(WebStoreDelegates.selectPromotions.Invoke(webStoreContext).ByID(dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTION.PROMOTION_ID).ToList().SingleOrDefault()); 

with - if (item.TBLPROMOTION != null) {
item.TBLPROMOTION.Clear();
webStoreContext.SaveChanges();}

This will remove all many-to-many promotion entries tied to this item.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question: replace -

```
if (dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTION != null) {
    dbItem.TBLPROMOTION.Remove(WebStoreDelegates.selectPromotions
    .Invoke(webStoreContext).ByID(dbItem.TBLITEM.TBLPROMOTION.PROMOTION_ID)
    .ToList().SingleOrDefault()); 
}
```

with -

```
if (item.TBLPROMOTION != null) { 
     item.TBLPROMOTION.Clear(); 
     webStoreContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will remove all many-to-many promotion entries tied to this item